# How to Change button text of messagebox control in nsis?

Tags: installation, nsis

I want to change the Messagebox OkCancel of nsis to continue setup and remove .Is it possible to do with resource hacker.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Yes, This can be done with writing a custom plugin...

It is a normal win32 dll with exported functions. The only "documentation" is the [example plugin](http://sourceforge.net/p/nsis/code/HEAD/tree/) and its header files.

Comment: Can  you give some example how to write it

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Buttons_Header) is how to do it without using Resource Hacker.

Comment: I clear mentioned in my question i want to change message box  button text change.I think the answer u have pasted for next cancel and previous button.

Comment: Ok.. My bad..didn't saw the messagebox thingy.. guess you'll need to write your own custom plugin for that.

Comment: any idea How can i write that .Any example.